# c# - Microsoft Graph API - Permissions on DriveItem not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am creating a `DriveItem` as a `Folder` using Microsoft Graph and I am trying to set the permissions to "replace". I have tried the following:

```
var driveItem = new DriveItem
{
    Name = Customer_Name.Text + Customer_LName.Text,
    Folder = new Folder { },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    { 
        { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" }
    }
};

var newFolder = await App.GraphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Items["item.ID"]
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(driveItem);
```

When I run the code the first time everything is cool, but the second time I get this error:

> You cannot get content for a folder

Which is super weird...what am I doing wrong? Or is there a way to get the `DriveItem` by name to get the id?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't really clear on this point, but `"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"` isn't a valid option for Folders. If you consider the implications `replace` would have here, it would potentially result in any child files or folders getting unintentionally erased.

As for using the path rather than the id, you can do this by replacing `Item["id"]` with `ItemWithPath("item/with/path")`:

```
var folder  = await App.GraphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("folder name")
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

You could retrieve it's children using:

```
var childItems = await App.GraphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("folder name")
    .Children
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```